# I am fairly new to Java, can anyone help me make my code more efficient?

Tags: java

The goal of this code is to take user input regarding two sides of a quadrilateral and output the perimeter and area of the shape. I am very new to the language of Java, hence why these errors are most likely solved with one or two minor edits. If anyone with experience coding Java could help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quadrilateral
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    double area, perimeter;
    String answer;

    Scanner ans1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Is your desired shape 2-dimensional or 3-dimensional: 2d or 3d");
    answer = ans1.next();

    switch(answer)
    {
      case "2d":
        System.out.println("Good, you shall be allowed to continue.");
        break;

      case "3d":
        System.out.println("You are bad and should feel bad.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter your first side length: \n");
    double side1 = keys.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter your second side length: \n");
    double side2 = keys.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("The perimeter of your desired shape is: \n", perimeter(side1, side2));
    System.out.println("The area is: \n", area(side1, side2));

  }
  public static double area(double side1, double side2)
  {
    area = side1 * side2;
    return(area);
  }

  public static double perimeter(double side1, double side2)
  {
    perimeter = (2 * side1) + (2 * side2);
    return(perimeter);
  }
}
```

Comment: You say you get errors what are they?

Comment: please clearly describe what the errors are, and if you are able to build your program, describe how you test it, and what are the observed and expected outputs. you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if needed

Answer (score 0):

Its good with few errors. Here is the compilable version of code. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Quadrilateral {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        double area, perimeter;
        String answer;

        Scanner ans1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Is your desired shape 2-dimensional or 3-dimensional: 2d or 3d");
        answer = ans1.next();

        switch (answer) {
          case "2d":
            System.out.println("Good, you shall be allowed to continue.");
            break;

          case "3d":
            System.out.println("You are bad and should feel bad.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your first side length: \n");
        double side1 = keys.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter your second side length: \n");
        double side2 = keys.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("The perimeter of your desired shape is: \n" + perimeter(side1, side2));
        System.out.println("The area is: \n" + area(side1, side2));

      }

      public static double area(double side1, double side2) {
        return side1 * side2;
      }

      public static double perimeter(double side1, double side2) {
        return ((2 * side1) + (2 * side2));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about scope of variables. You declare `double area, perimeter;` inside of `main` which means that those variables are *local* to main which means anywhere outside of main they no longer exist.

You need to declare `double perimeter` inside of the perimeter method and then return it and vice versa for area.

Or you could just not use a variable in these methods and simply `return side1 * side2`